# Why is the output for x=5 not 2 3 4 5 6

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int x;
printf("enter number >");
scanf("%d",&x);
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
i=i+1;                          
printf("%d ",i);
}
```

Doesn't it operate like this in C language?
for x=5

```
i=1      2=1+1
  
i=2      3=2+1
  
i=3      4=3+1
i=4      5=4+1
  
i=5      6=5+1
```

output should be 2 3 4 5 6 then
but the output is 2 4 6 why ?

Comment: you forget the `i++` part in the for loop ?

Comment: no , I know that i++ and i=i+1 are the same, my problem is whether there is an error in the output, when I calculate it myself, I find the output of 2 3 4 5 6, but it shows 2 4 6 in the program.

Comment: You increment your counter twice in each loop, once with `i=i+1` inside of the loop and once with `i++` in the `for` instruction, so the value of `i` will only iterate on even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing the value of 'i' two times per iteration:

- first time inside the code block of the loop;
- second time the already increased value is being incremented as last step of the loop (i++);

So, if x=5, here what's happening:

**first iteration:**

```
i = 1
```

Loop enters it's body, where:
i = i + 1 = 1+1 = 2

printf prints the current value of 'i' which is 2, and then loop goes to incrementation step:

```
i++;
```

there you additionally increment the value of 'i' wit +1 (via postfix ++ operator for incrementation), so:

```
i++ = i+1 = 2+1 = 3
i = 3;
```

Then the loop goes back to the condition check, to see if 'i' is still <= 5.
3<=5 = true, so the loop will execute it's code block once more:

**second interation:**

```
i = 3;
```

Loop enters it's body, where:

```
i = i + 1 = 3+1 = 4
```

printf prints the current value of 'i' which is 4, and then loop goes to incrementation step:

```
i++ = i+1 = 4+1 = 5
i = 5;
```

Then the loop goes back to the condition check, to see if i is still <= 5.
5<=5 = true, so the loop will execute it's code block once more:

**Third interation:**

```
i = 5;
```

Loop enters it's body, where:

```
i = i + 1 = 5+1 = 6
```

printf prints the current value of 'i' which is 6, and then loop goes to incrementation step:

```
i++ = i+1 = 6+1 = 7
i = 7;
```

Then the loop goes back to the condition check, to see if 'i' is still <= 5.
7<=5 = false, so loop will end it's execution and program will proceed forward with next instructions.

Answer (score 2):

i++ increments the variable i to fix your code

```
int x;
printf("enter number >");
scanf("%d",&x);
for(int i=1;i<=x;)
{
   i++;
   printf("%d ",i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
i=i+1; /* This statement increments i, now i = 2 */
printf("%d ",i); /* This, then prints 2. 
}
```

The third part of the `for` loop then increments `i` again.

On the second iteration,
`i = i + 1` increments `i` to `4`.... and so on.

Remove this statement from your code:

```
i = i + 1;
```

And then it should work as expected.